# Enable MatDatepicker input box border visibility when input box is disabled

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-ui

I want to enable input box visibility. When I am disabling the mat input box the border is not visible.

My Code: -

From Date

                        
Invaild Date

I have tried giving inline styles with important and also tried refered to stackoverflow which told me to add

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-enabled

in angular component css file.

Comment: _"My Code: -"_ - please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, and then fix your question.